# Does c_str Always Return the Same Address?

Tags: c++, string, c-strings, c++03

I know that C++11 has made quite a few changes to the `string`. Not the least of which is requiring it to be laid out linearly in memory.

Prior to C++11 a call to `string::c_str` would return a `const char*` but is it guaranteed to be the same one. For example, given `string foo`, is this guaranteed to be true, or might they return different addresses?

```
foo.c_str() == foo.c_str()
```

**EDIT:** I should have appended that I'm asking if the return of `string::c_str` will always be consistent as long as no method is called  on `foo` which would have invalidated its iterators.

Comment: Might as well be a cross-site duplicate: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/125149/17853 (I'm sure there are plenty on SO too though)

Comment: _"Prior to C++11 a call to string::c_str would return a const char* but is it guaranteed to be the same one"_ this is wrong statement. result of `c_str` _may_ change after any non-const function. Try for example to append a long (say 2048 `char`s) string to your initially short string

Comment: @mvidelgauz I assume he meant "the same one" without iterator invalidation (ie: through a call to a non-const member function)

Comment: Why do you want or need to rely on it being the same?

Comment: @KABoissonneault then the answer should be yes - as long as no non-const functions were called on the object internal buffer is not relocated and it was guaranteed also prior to C++11 - result of `c_str` is valid until first (possible) mutation

Comment: correction to my first comment: 2048 will likely not enough, try >4096, which is usually memory allocation page - almost guaranteed (virtual) relocation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: Reading the same paragraph from the standard, I now conclude that subsequent calls to methods data()/c_str() are allowed to invalidate the previously returned pointer (even if you haven't done anything else), so the answer to your question would be **No**, how ironic.

Original answer:

Yes, as long as the only non-const operations you perform on the object are **operator[]**, **at**, **begin**, **rbegin**, **end**, and **rend**.

data()/c_str() returns a pointer to the first element of the string. See the standard (N1905), p. 21.3 [Class template basic_string]:

> 6. References, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements of a basic_string sequence may be invalidated by the
>      following uses of that basic_string object:
>
> — As an argument to non-member functions swap() (21.3.7.8), operator>>() (21.3.7.9), and getline() (21.3.7.9).
>
> — As an argument to basic_string::swap().
>
> — Calling data() and c_str() member functions.
>
> — Calling non-const member functions, except **operator[], at, begin, rbegin, end, and rend**.
>
> — Following construction or any of the above uses, except the forms of insert and erase that return iterators, the first call to non-const member functions operator[], at, begin, rbegin, end, or rend.

Comment: You dropped a "non-const" in the first sentence.

Comment: Wow, so 2 subsequent calls to `string::c_str` could invalidate references to elements of a `basic_string` sequence. I expected there to be a lot more hoops that had to be jumped through to prove that, not something so direct. Thank you for finding such a relevant quote from the standard! I'll accept after the answer has had a weekend in the sun.